# MouseProc hook and WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK

Tags: c++, windows, double-click, mouse-hook

I have a hook setup for getting mouse events in a plugin I develop. I need to get the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, and I expect the message flow to be:

`WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`

If I call the next hook when dealing with the first `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, then the flow is as expected. However, if I return my own result, then the expected double click comes as a mouse down message. Any idea why this is happening? I need the message to stop after I handle it, and not have it passed to the next hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having done a little reading over at the MSDN, I think the explanation of this behaviour lies in this remark on the [`WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606(VS.85).aspx) page:

> Only windows that have the `CS_DBLCLKS`
>   style can receive `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`
>   messages, which the system generates
>   whenever the user presses, releases,
>   and again presses the left mouse
>   button within the system's
>   double-click time limit.

If your program is returning a nonzero value when it handles `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` or `WM_LBUTTONUP`, then those messages aren't sent to the target window -- as expected. However, my inference, based on the above quote, is that since no window with the `CS_DBLCLKS` style is therefore receiving the messages (since the hook prevents *any* window from receiving the messages), the system therefore doesn't feel like it needs to generate a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`.

To put it another way, the system only generates a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` **if and only if** (a) a window receives the previous `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP` messages and (b) that window has the `CS_DBLCLKS` style. Since your hook prevents condition (a) from being satisfied, `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` is never generated and so a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message is sent instead.

As to a workaround, I doubt there's a perfect solution. I assume the reason why you want to receive the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message is so your hook knows whether or not a regular `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message represents the second click of a double-click, right? In that case, what you could do is read the double-click time from the registry as Faisal suggests and have your hook measure the time between `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages, however there's a large chance that you will get inaccurate results (due to the lag time between the messages being sent). Alternatively if there's some way you could instead redirect the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`/`WM_LBUTTONUP` messages to maybe a hidden window that your hook owns (which has the `CS_DBLCLKS` style), the system may end up generating a `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message and sending it to your hidden window, which you can then process in that window's `WndProc` (though I don't have a lot of experience with hooking so I don't know if this is possible).

Comment: GRB, thanks for the input. It makes a lot of sense. I ended up using the first workaround you mentioned and it seems to work well (at least on my machine). We'll see how well the users like it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling  CallNextHookEx() before returning your own result - according to MSDN's documentation [MouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28VS.85%29.aspx) it is highly recommended that you call it since when you return your own result you prevent other hooks from being called.

Have you considered using a [low level mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986%28VS.85%29.aspx)?  It doesn't require your DLL to be injected into the process being hooked and I find it to be a more consistent and powerful hook (albeit more resource intensive if not coded appropriately) - especially when listening for clicks in some legacy applications (there was one that was coded in ancient delphi) and clicks in applications served via terminal servers (citrix).
The only issue with low level mouse hooks is that they don't receive double clicks per se - which means you have to query the registry for the 'DoubleClickSpeed' and then check for two mouse down events within that interval before triggering a double click.

Comment: I think he *wants* to prevent other hooks from receiving the messages by failing to call `CallNextHookEx()` (the merits/ethics of which I won't touch on). The problem, though (if I'm reading this right), is that when he does, his program receives a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message in lieu of `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, behaviour I don't have an answer for.

Comment: Faisal, my plugin builds on top of the UI of the software I'm plugging into. So when I get a click on something in my UI, I don't want the main program to get the click because that could modify things and I lose the original state of the program.